# How to test if the user's browser support certain ciphers and show a friendly message if it doesn't

Tags: tls1.2, browser-security

In very short, how can I show the visitors of my website with a message if their browser/client doesn't support any of the TLS cipher-suite enabled on the application web server?

I have an existing web-application that attracts a lot of users. Due to security reasons, I want to enable only certain secure ciphers on the webserver and disable all weak TLS ciphers. This will possibly restrict some users to access my website if their browser doesn't support any of the allowed ciphers. In such a case, I want to show a friendly message to those users on their browser, instead of any default message from the browser.

One method I can think of is to: Show a popup to the users when they visit my website. I am not sure if there are any other better ways to achieve this. Hence, I am seeking some solutions to achieve the desired results which are widely used and accepted.

Comment: What's a cipher? What's a cipher-suite? What?

Comment: @chiliNUT In cryptography, a cipher is an algorithm for performing encryption or decryption. Please read this - shorturl.at/ervC7

Comment: Oh nvm, looks like most browsers support tls1.2 except safari might have problems, I think I understand your question now. You might wanna add tls1.2 to your question description instead of just the tag.

Comment: Good point @chiliNUT. Added TLS in description. ta